# Javascript: Promise() .then doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a loader animation style for my website. The loading animation is 16 bars which increase and decrease in order. For example, the first bar will increase and then decrease back to its original size. Then the next bar will repeat this process until all bars have done it, then stop the process and reveal the page. In this case, because JavaScript is asynchronous on calling functions, I used a promise to get around it. The use of promise is to animate the bar after the previous has completed animating. Currently, my code animates only the first bar and stops there. It doesn't continue to animate the rest of them. Below are all of my codes:

**IMPORTANT!**
The issue it on javascript. Don't spend time on HTML or CSS.

```js
var index = -1;

function loading(){
 var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
 display = window.getComputedStyle(loader).display;
 if (display == "block"){
  var child = document.getElementById("loader-ul").getElementsByTagName("div");
  index = index + 1;
  alert("dd");
  animate(child);
 }
}

function animate(element){
 var el = element[index];
 var MaxHeight = false;
 var finished = false;
 function anim(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
   if (finished == false){
    if (MaxHeight == false){
     var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).height.slice(0, -2));
     var Bot = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(el).bottom.slice(0, -2));
     height = height + 1;
     Bot = Bot + 0.5;
     el.style.bottom = Bot + "px";
     el.style.height = height + "px";
     if (height <= 100){
      window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
     }
     else{
      MaxHeight = true;
     }
    }
    if (MaxHeight == true){
     var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).height.slice(0, -2));
     var Bot = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(el).bottom.slice(0, -2));
     height = height - 1;
     Bot = Bot - 0.5;
     el.style.bottom = Bot + "px";
     el.style.height = height + "px";
     if (height >= 50){
      window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
     }
     else{
      MaxHeight = true;
      finished = true;
      el.style.bottom = 0 + "px";
      el.style.height = 50 + "px";
     }
    }
   }
   else{
    resolve();
   }
  });
 }
 anim().then(loading);
}
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: auto;
}

#loader{
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 9999;
}

#loader .center{
 position: relative;
 height: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: red;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 margin: auto;
}

#loader .center div{
 width: 2px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body onload="loading()">
    <div id="loader">
   <div class="center" id="loader-ul">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

I also have a link to jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6227jjen/

Thank you all!

Note:
I have added some alerts for debugging purposes.

Comment: Please remove your HTML and CSS, it's irrelevant to the issue and clutters your question.

Comment: I agree but I added only to run the snipped.

Comment: There's an issue with your fiddle -- see the console: loading is not defined. You need to no wrap in <head> in your JS options.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: `resolve()` is not called at `anim`.

Comment: it's called in the else statement inside the promise function.

Comment: _"it's called in the else statement inside the promise function"_ No, `resolve()` is not called. Logic does not reach that `else` block. You can check this by including `console.log("resolve")` within `else` block above `resolve()` call. At what point is `resolve()` expected to be called?

Comment: I see now, I changed it to the other else statement: else{
      MaxHeight = true;
      finished = true;
      el.style.bottom = 0 + "px";
      el.style.height = 50 + "px";
      resolve();
     } but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `resolve()` still does not appear to be called. Should `resolve()` be called when `anim()` is called 101 times?

Comment: No, but after it finishes the animation.

Comment: At what point is animation complete? Note, you could probably substitute using `.animate()` for `requestAnimationFrame` to resolve issue

Comment: Once the bar has returned to its original size from resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that not all path leads to resolve.  The bigger problem is that your code creates a lot of promises instead of one.  Here is the outline of the change.

```
function anim () {
  return new Promise (function (resolve) {
    function _anim () {
      if (!finished) {
          _logic();
          // By putting requestAnimationFrame at the end, you can ensure 
          // that it will be called after your logic
          // (assuming finished eventually equals true).
          window.requestAnimationFrame(_anim);
      }
     else 
       resolve();
    }
  });
```

Here is the actual fix.

```js
var index = -1;

function loading() {
  var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
  display = window.getComputedStyle(loader).display;
  if (display == "block") {
    var child = document.getElementById("loader-ul").getElementsByTagName("div");
    index = index + 1;
    alert("dd");
    animate(child);
  }
}

function animate(element) {
  var el = element[index];
  var MaxHeight = false;
  var finished = false;

  function anim() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      function _anim() {
        if (finished == false) {
          if (MaxHeight == false) {
            var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).height.slice(0, -2));
            var Bot = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(el).bottom.slice(0, -2));
            height = height + 1;
            Bot = Bot + 0.5;
            el.style.bottom = Bot + "px";
            el.style.height = height + "px";
            if (height > 100) {
              MaxHeight = true;
            }
          }
          if (MaxHeight == true) {
            var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).height.slice(0, -2));
            var Bot = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(el).bottom.slice(0, -2));
            height = height - 1;
            Bot = Bot - 0.5;
            el.style.bottom = Bot + "px";
            el.style.height = height + "px";
            if (height < 50) {
              MaxHeight = true;
              finished = true;
              el.style.bottom = 0 + "px";
              el.style.height = 50 + "px";
            }
          }
          window.requestAnimationFrame(_anim);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      }
      _anim();
    });
  }
  anim().then(loading);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}
#loader {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#loader .center {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: auto;
}
#loader .center div {
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body onload="loading()">
  <div id="loader">
    <div class="center" id="loader-ul">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code works exactly as I wanted, thank you! Can you explain me like a 5-year-old why your code works and my doesn't? I need to understand why this works and my doesn't.

Comment: For promise to work, all code paths within must reaches param1 (result) or param2 (reject) or throw an error.  The only way to reach `result` is if finish === true, but the code path that sets finish = true never calls `window.requestAnimationFrame(anim)`, so `loading` never gets called again.  Even if `window.requestAnimationFrame(anim)` was called from that path, the promise was not the one from anim().then(loading), but the last `window.requestAnimationFrame(anim)` called.  I tried not to change your code from top to bottom so can still see what changed.

Comment: Thank you, I understand and it works. You made my day!

Comment: "*The bigger problem is that your code creates a lot of promises instead of one.*" - not at all. Calling asynchronous functions (`requestAnimationFrame`) multiple times *should* create multiple promises.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);` will never resolve your promise. It will call `anim` which will create another promise which might then get resolved if you're finished, but the original promise is never fulfilled.

Instead of wrapping the whole body of `anim` in a `new Promise` constructor, you should promisify only `requestAnimationFrame` and then use that to build a promise chain.

```
function animate(element){
    var el = element[index];
    var MaxHeight = false;
    var finished = false;
    function getFrame() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
        });
    }
    function anim(){
        if (finished == false){
            if (MaxHeight == false){
                var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).height.slice(0, -2));
                var Bot = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(el).bottom.slice(0, -2));
                height = height + 1;
                Bot = Bot + 0.5;
                el.style.bottom = Bot + "px";
                el.style.height = height + "px";
                if (height <= 100){
                    return getFrame().then(anim);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                } else{
                    MaxHeight = true;
                }
            }
            if (MaxHeight == true){
                var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).height.slice(0, -2));
                var Bot = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(el).bottom.slice(0, -2));
                height = height - 1;
                Bot = Bot - 0.5;
                el.style.bottom = Bot + "px";
                el.style.height = height + "px";
                if (height >= 50){
                    return getFrame().then(anim);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                } else{
                    MaxHeight = true;
                    finished = true;
                    el.style.bottom = 0 + "px";
                    el.style.height = 50 + "px";
                }
            }
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    return anim().then(loading);
}
```

Comment: I am bit confused. Can you post the code that you are talking about please?

Comment: I had some parenthesis too much, can you try again? It should work.